# Big O Running Time Analysis

Tags: asymptotics

What is the big O running time for following `method()` by counting the approximate number operation it performs. How can I identify the running time of each line? I mean when is 1, n or n^2..?

```
static int do(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (n-1); i++) {
        j == i;
        while (j != 0) {
            if ( (j%2) == 0)
               count++;
            j = j/2;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

static int method(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + do(i);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: We get this kind of question a lot, so we've created several reference questions on the subject: http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844.  Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered.

Comment: @D.W. Noted. I will go thru your posted link and learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`O(1)` when you are accessing or assigning a single variable

```
int number = array[index];
```

`O(n)` when you iterate over `n` elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   //code
}
```

`O(n^2)` when you iterate `n` times over `n` elements (nested loop)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
      //code
   }
}
```